# Distribution of functions of multivariate random variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, random-variables, normal-distribution

We define  the coverage probability $P_{cov}$,  i.e., the probability that the blockage probability  of $m$ independent communication links is less than the threshold
$P_{th}$ as
\begin{align}
   P_{cov} &=P\left(\prod_{i=1}^{m}\left(a+\frac{b}{(h_i-h_R)}\right)\le P_{th}\right), \nonumber \\
\end{align}
where $a$ and $b \in(0,1)$. $h_R=1.4$ and each $h_i$ is an independent  normal distribution random variable, and is much larger than $h_R$. How to calculate  the closed-form $P_{cov}$?

For example  when $m=1$,
\begin{align}
   P_{cov} &= P\left(h \ge H_{th} \right)    
  =1-\int_{h_{min}}^{H_{th}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-{\frac{{(h-\mu)}^{2}}{2{\sigma}^2}}}}d{h}   \nonumber  \\
   & \approx\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{H_{th}-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right).
    %1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-{\frac{{(h_i-\mu)}^{2}}{2{\sigma}^2}}}
\end{align}
where  $H_{th}=(\frac{b}{(P_{th}-a)}+h_R)$.

when $m\ge1$
\begin{align}
   P_{cov} = ?
\end{align}

Comment: Could you briefly describe the scenario or modeling of such a construct? Does the "cov" stand for covering of some kind? When providing clarification, please edit the body of the post instead of commenting.

Comment: @Lee David Chung Lin Thanks for your comments!  We have edited the body of the post.